# Changing the value in one column based on a subset of values of another column in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset that contains columns city and country.  Some of the country columns are incorrectly mislabelled as 'Other'.  I know this because some of the city values contain labels like saddle lake (Canada).  Is there a way I can search a subset of the value in the city to change the value in Country.  IE search for any city value containing the word 'Canada' and change country to 'Canada'.  I'd like to do this for multiple countries including the USA and UK.  which might mean my search would need an 'or' element and search usa, US, USA etc

Current dataset:

- City              - Country
- Saddle(Canada)    - Other
- Dublin            -  Other
- Detroit           - USA
- Vancouver         - Canada
- NYC: US           - Other

Output:

- Saddle(Canada)    - Canada
- Dublin             -Other
- Detroit       - USA
- Vancouver        - Canada
- NYC: US      - USA

I've played around with if statements using grep() but no success.

Edit: some code I have tried:

```
for (i in Data$city){
  if (Data$city == '.*canada*.'){
  Data$country = Canada
}}
```

Comment: In the data showed, there are two patterns `(Canada)` and `: US.  What other patterns are present in your original data

Comment: there are 9000 values so I won't be able to pick up on all the patterns.  Basically I need a way to partially match a value in a string.  So search for the word Canada within the string and if found the country value will change to Canada etc